# Heroku master push error with Xcode dependencies?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xcode, heroku, bundle, cocoapods

I am trying to push my rails app to heroku and there is a problem with installing the xcodeproj gem.
After running git push heroku master, dependencies are installed until it gets here:

```
   Installing xcodeproj (0.6.0)
   Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
   /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
   checking for -std=c99 option to compiler... yes
   checking for CoreFoundation... no
   checking for main() in -lCoreFoundation... no
   CoreFoundation is needed to build the Xcodeproj C extension.
   *** extconf.rb failed ***
   Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
   necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
   details.  You may need configuration options.
   Provided configuration options:
   --with-opt-dir
   --without-opt-dir
   --with-opt-include
   --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
   --with-opt-lib
   --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
   --with-make-prog
   --without-make-prog
   --srcdir=.
   --curdir
   --ruby=/usr/local/bin/ruby
   --with-CoreFoundationlib
   --without-CoreFoundationlib
   Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_t2ezgq9t6vp6/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/xcodeproj-0.6.0 for inspection.
   Results logged to /tmp/build_t2ezgq9t6vp6/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/xcodeproj-0.6.0/ext/xcodeproj/gem_make.out
   An error occurred while installing xcodeproj (0.6.0), and Bundler cannot
   continue.
       Make sure that `gem install xcodeproj -v '0.6.0'` succeeds before bundling.
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/Rails app
```

I have looked for errors similar to this - and many people have gotten this error when installing Cocoapods. I installed cocoapods with these dependencies no problem, the command line tool is working, and I've already started working in xcode (4.6.2). I am running latest RVM 1.19.6 and rails 3.2.13

It's not a problem with the database- I have production 'pg' - and I've already deployed to Heroku - the problem is something within the xcode/cocoapods dependency.
Have you heard of any incompatibility between heroku and any of this?
I can't figure 
I need to push the rails app to link up the json files with RestKit etc. This is the only thing holding me up before moving to xcode so I really want to solve this.
Any help you can offer would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will probably be hard to solve: the line `checking for CoreFoundation... no` tells me that it probably isn't portable to Linux (which Heroku is ultimately running): it depends on Apple's [CoreFoundation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_Foundation) library. *Really* clever tinkering might be able to build it using either [GNUStep](http://www.gnustep.org/)'s Objective C toolchain or (less likely) even via [opencflite](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencflite/), but that'd probably be a pretty uphill battle.

Although being able to generate your XCode project 'in the cloud' like that certainly would be nifty! But something akin to [MacinCloud](http://www.macincloud.com/) is probably a way easier option.

Comment: Thanks - ya - I ended up cloning everything except the cocoapods stuff and finishing all of the rails side things before bundling cocoa and moving to xcode as a work around.. Thanks for the input!